# How to run React-pdf (@react-pdf/renderer) with typescript on NodeJS + Express JS?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, express, react-pdf

I'm not able to run React-Pdf (@react-pdf/renderer) using typescript on Express JS server. I'm trying to run it using babel but it is not working. These are the errors which I'm getting.

[build error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLowx.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31HcY.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srU6W.png)

Github repo for the same -
[Github Repo](https://github.com/shenoymithun70/react-pdf-typescript-express)

When I'm trying to build the project using typescript I'm getting these errors. It is working when I'm trying to create the same on a express js server using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the path in the first screenshot, it seems like your JSX code is written in a `.ts` file.

You should change the file type to `.tsx`, and it should compile successfully without type errors.